# How do I generate a number after a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, random, guid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a GUID / UUID in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

I need to have a script that generates random numbers and letters with a form that looks like this:

`M3KRT-CKKYV-YH4G4-YXP42-46FMT`

Prefer jQuery, or javascript. I know how to generate number when the button is click using the `.click()` method in jQuery. But I can not find out how to actually make the code :(

Comment: You should be doing this server-side.

Comment: I don't have time to mess with that. I just really need this in a JS way.

Comment: "I can not find out how to actually make the code." I feel like this sentence is missing a few words.

Comment: The GUID example is a good one but it's 4 characters.  See my post for a modified version to include 5.

Comment: made it a simple call, use it if you like: http://jsbin.com/ucobo4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this: [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you include [Win7 license key](http://www.google.com/search?q=M3KRT-CKKYV-YH4G4-YXP42-46FMT) in your question?

Comment: I thought it looked familiar...  But this isn't an answer, it should be a comment on the question.

Comment: +1 for (some definition of) hack value

Answer (score 1):

Modified this example a little:

[Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

And came up with this:

```
function S5() {
    return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x100000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
}
function guid() {
    return (S5() + "-" + S5() + "-" + S5() + "-" + S5() + "-" + S5()).toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```
function createGuid () {
  for (var i=5, out=[]; i--;) {
    out.push((Math.random()*58786559+1679615|0).toString(36));
  }
  return out.join('-').toUpperCase();
}

alert(createGuid());
```